# R_How to select hyperprior distribution for Beta distribution parameter in R?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, beta-distribution, hyperparameter, weibull-distribution

I have 2-mixture weibull distrubution. And this distribution haver the portion parameter  θ whose value should lie between (0,1). Therefore, I am assuming the prior distribution of θθ to be a beta distribution with hyper-priors α and β ie. P(θ|α,β)=Beta(α,β)P(θ|α,β)=Beta(α,β).  Is there a way that I can assign some hyper prior distruibution to α and β ? Is there are any  there's a closed-form solution ? I attached my code. I need to assign value of prior[9], prior[10]. And i should have the find parameters of 2-mixture weibull distribution with bayesian method. Any recomendation would be very thank you.

```
# Mix_LF : loglikelyhood fn of 2-mixture distribution
# ga : parameter of  2-mixture distribution



Posterior <- function(param,Data1,ga,sigma){

if (param[1] <= 0) return(-Inf)  
if (param[2] <= 0) return(-Inf)
if (param[3] <= 0) return(-Inf)
if (param[4] <= 0) return(-Inf)
if (param[5] <= 0) return(-Inf) 

Likelihood <- - Mix_LF(c(param[1],param[2],param[3],param[4],param[5]),Data1)

prior[1] = ga[2]^2/sigma^2
prior[2] = sigma^2/ga[2]

prior1 <- sum(log(dgamma(param[1],shape=prior[2],scale=prior[1]))) #Gamma Prior

prior[3] = ga[3]^2/sigma^2
prior[4] = sigma^2/ga[3]

prior2 <- sum(log(dgamma(param[2],shape=prior[4],scale=prior[3]))) #Gamma Prior

prior[5] = ga[4]^2/sigma^2
prior[6] = sigma^2/ga[4]

prior3 <- sum(log(dgamma(param[3],shape=prior[6],scale=prior[5]))) #Gamma Prior

prior[7] = ga[5]^2/sigma^2
prior[8] = sigma^2/ga[5]

prior4 <- sum(log(dgamma(param[4],shape=prior[8],scale=prior[7]))) #Gamma Prior

prior[9] <- 2
prior[10] <- 5

prior5 <- sum(log(dbeta(param[5],prior[9],prior[10]))) #Beta Prior

value <- Likelihood + prior1 + prior2 + prior3 + prior4 + prior5

print(c(value,prior1,prior2,prior3,prior4,prior5))

if (is.na(value) == TRUE) return(-Inf)

if (is.nan(value) == TRUE) return(-Inf)

return(value)

}

ini = ga[2:6]
sigma = 1

#prior <-c(ga[2]^2/sigma^2,sigma^2/ga[2],ga[2]^2/sigma^2,sigma^2/ga[2],ga[2]^2/sigma^2,sigma^2/ga[2],ga[2]^2/sigma^2,sigma^2/ga[2], 2, 0.5)
prior <-c(ga[2]^2/sigma^2,sigma^2/ga[2],ga[3]^2/sigma^2,sigma^2/ga[3],ga[4]^2/sigma^2,sigma^2/ga[4],ga[5]^2/sigma^2,sigma^2/ga[5], 2, 0.5)

samp <- MCMCmetrop1R(Posterior, theta.init=ini, Data=Data1, ga=ga, sigma=sigma, thin=100, mcmc=100000, burnin=1000, verbose=0, tune=1)

param <- colMeans(samp)
```